# Trying to understand @ngrx select and AppState

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

i am currently struggling to understand how the select command of the @ngrx/store library is working.

We have the following code example:

```
export interface AppState {
  message: string;
  messages: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  message$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private store: Store<any>) {
    this.message$ = store.select<string>('message');
  }
}
```

My reducer looks like this

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface AppState {
  message: string;
  messages: string[];
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  message: 'Hello World',
  messages: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
};

export function messageReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SPANISH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hola Mundo'});
    case 'FRENCH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Bonjour le monde'});
    case 'GERMAN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hello World'});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function messagesReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SPANISH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hola Mundo'});
    case 'FRENCH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Bonjour le monde'});
    case 'GERMAN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hello World'});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And my template looks like that:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  {{ (message$ | async) }}
  <button (click)="getGermanMessage()">Deutsche Version</button>
  <button (click)="getSpanishMessage()">Spanische Version</button>
  <button (click)="getFrenchMessage()">Französische Version</button>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So my misunderstanding comes from the line

```
this.message$ = this.store.select('message');
```

I thought i would get an Observable of the string type and could use like that in my template:

```
{{ message$ | async }}
```

and i would get the value that is present in the store, but as far as i could see it, i get an object where i have to select the specific properties, but what does the 'message' string do in that line if not selecting the requested property of the store? Seems like i have a lack of knowledge of some part, but i don`t know what i am missing.

So what i get in my template is

```
[object Object]
```

This is how my store lookss like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpKrI.jpg

Maybe this makes it more clear. I don`t understand why i don`t get an observable of the message value from the store like state.message but get the state itself as object when i do:

```
this.message$ = this.store.select('message');
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each property of your AppState should have a reducer:

**app.module.ts**

```
StoreModule.provideStore(
  { 
      message: messageReducer, 
      messages: messagesReducer
  })
```

**app-state.ts**

```
export interface AppState {
    message: string,
    messages: string[]    
}
```

**messageReducer.ts**

```
export function simpleReducer(state = '', action: Action) {
    ...
    return state;
}
```

**component.ts**

Within any component you can subscribe to any change to any property (or sub-property) of your AppState:

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
  this.message$ = store.select<string>("message");
  this.messages$ = store.select<string[]>("messages")
}
```

I'm not sure if you wanted one reducer or two. Based on your AppState (which should contain properties for each reducer for your entire app), I'm assuming you want two.

The `select` is an rxjs [select](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md), which is also an alias for map - nothing special.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means i need a reducer for every property i need or i want to display. Yeah i guess i wanted two reducer there, but i did not get the concept behind that. You made it more clear. Thank you

Comment: So is it best practice to have a reducer for each property my state has?

Comment: It is the way that @ngrx/store expects you to setup your app state according to their documentation.  I think the best practice is to think about which reducers you need (could complex objects, or as simple as a string), then create a reducer for it.  Then register the reducer with your store when you setup your AppModule.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, i used two reducers now for each property. So i still have to use {{ (message$ | async)?.message }} to get the message from my app state, so this is the way i need to use the store?

Comment: No, message$ is an Observable<string> so you just need to do {{ message$ | async }}

Comment: yes thats what i did, but in my view i only got [object Object] now. Thats what i don`t understand. I will update my post above to make it more clear what i have done

Comment: `messageReducer` should have an initial state that maps to a property of your AppState. Since the `message` is a string, then the initial state of `messageReducer` should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my misunderstanding. Thanks pixelbits for your help. What i did now is to return a string in the message reducer instead of the state object, so i would get a string and not the state object

```
export function messageReducer(state: string = 'Hello World', action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SPANISH':
      return 'Hola Mundo';
    case 'FRENCH':
      return 'Bonjour le monde';
    case 'GERMAN':
      return 'Hello World';
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

instead of

```
export function messagesReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SPANISH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hola Mundo'});
    case 'FRENCH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Bonjour le monde'});
    case 'GERMAN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {message: 'Hello World'});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```